# How can i make my total score 10 not 30?

Tags: php, variables

Basically what the title says.

Code:

```
$score = 0;
$totalScore = 0;

$totalScore+=1;
if(@$_POST['Q1'] == 'Reggae')
{
echo "";
$score += 1;

}
```

This is basically an example of 1 question's answer, as you can see if you get this right you get 1 point. But as there is 30 questions, but only 10 are displayed at once the `$totalScore` is still set at 30. How can I make the equation to make it out of 10? Please :)

Comment: Sorry. I am creating a quiz using php. And every time it is run a randomised 10 out of 30 questions are shown, each time the person gets a score correct its +1 to the score. 

The total score is saying it's out of 30, because there is 30 quesitons, not 10 how it should be.. i hope that makes it easier to understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the variable's initial value to `$totalScore = 10;` and remove all `$totalScore+=1;`